# How to selectively toggle OpenCV's VideoWriter based on user actions

Tags: python, opencv

Suppose I have a number of video clips which are supposed to show a particular sequence of steps but when the clips were created they may have included unwanted action before or after the event.

Would it be possible to use OpenCV to automatically play the video frame by frame  so an operator can then hit a key when they see the start of the required action and another when the sequence is finished and have that portion of the video saved as new smaller more accurate video of the sequence.

> The code below will read in the webcam frame by frame, flip the frame before writing to a video until the user hits the `q`key on their keyboard.

How would I ensure the user could watch the stream of frames as they come in, then when they see the event they are interested in they can toggle the VideoWriter to start writing those frames to disk but the operator wouldn't need to constantly hit a key to send each frame to the VideoWriter and when the operator sees the event is over they can toggle the VideoWriter off again

```
import numpy as np
import cv2

cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

# Define the codec and create VideoWriter object
fourcc = cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc(*'XVID')
out = cv2.VideoWriter('output.avi',fourcc, 20.0, (640,480))

while(cap.isOpened()):
    ret, frame = cap.read()
    if ret==True:
        frame = cv2.flip(frame,0)

        # write the flipped frame
        out.write(frame)

        cv2.imshow('frame',frame)
        if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
            break
    else:
        break

# Release everything if job is finished
cap.release()
out.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: I know its possible to capture mouse actions but am i correct in thinking the left mouse button down action could be used as a toggle so that while as long as the mouse button is held the frames would be written to a new video and when its released it means stop recording but continue playback http://opencv-python-tutroals.readthedocs.io/en/latest/py_tutorials/py_gui/py_mouse_handling/py_mouse_handling.html

Answer (score 1):

After thinking about it, writing the video frame by frame wouldn't be a great use of resources and might not scale.

I'll expand this code to write the event data to a CSV file and use that in conjunction with MoviePy to extract the subclips based on the timestamps recorded when the left mouse button was down

If others can improve on the solution I'd welcome their input

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
cap = cv2.VideoCapture('YourVideoFile.mp4')

#Define the Mouse Callback Function
def record_action(event,x,y,flags,param):
    if event == cv2.EVENT_LBUTTONDOWN:
        print "Left Button Down @ " + str(cap.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_POS_MSEC)) + " milliseconds into video \n"
    elif event == cv2.EVENT_LBUTTONUP:
        print "Left Button Up @ " + str(cap.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_POS_MSEC)) + " milliseconds into video \n"

#Need to use a Named Window so it can be referenced in the mouse definition 
#and used when outputting the frames from the video in the imshow call later on
cv2.namedWindow("RecordMe")
#Bind the function above to the window
cv2.setMouseCallback("RecordMe",record_action)

while True:
    ret, frame = cap.read()
    #Use NamedWindow we created earlier to show the frames
    cv2.imshow('RecordMe',frame)
    if cv2.waitKey(30) & 0xff == ord('q'):
        break

cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```